# IOS/Objective-C: UIBarButtonItem with Custom Color Image

Tags: ios, image, uibarbuttonitem

I am trying to show a UIBarButtonItem with a custom image in my navigation bar.  If I just set the image in storyboard, it does not render properly. Instead of a proper image, I get a blue block.

Accordingly, following answers on SO and elsewhere, I tried to create the button programatically using the code below.  However, when I try this, nothing display at all.  Of note, I do have another button created in storyboard on the left side of the nav.

Could the other button be interfering?  Or is there somethign wrong with code below?  Would appreciate any suggestions:

```
 NSString *imageName = @"headshot-32.png";
UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:imageName] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    UIBarButtonItem* profileButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:image style: UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(profilePicPressed)];

    //this is what shows button in navbar:
   self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = @[profileButton];
```

Edit:

This code works for some reason...  Not sure what was wrong with above code:

```
UIBarButtonItem *profileBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"headshot-32.png"] landscapeImagePhone:[UIImage imageNamed:@"headshot-32.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(profilePicPressed)];  
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = @[profileBtn];
```

Comment: Are you trying to show 2 buttons on the left? The one you create in storyboard and the one you are adding via code?

Comment: Yes.  However, at moment i just want the one created in storyboard to display.  So I left the lefBarButtonItem out of the items array in above code.

Comment: Is your "headshot-32.png" image 20 x 20 pts?

Comment: It is 32x32  I have gotten it to work with  code in edit.  Not sure what was wrong with first code.

Comment: I think the issue has something to do with the other buttons there in storyboard.  It appears and disappears depending on how many buttons I put in the items array